# How to Sanitize HTML Received from an API Call in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I am looking for a good library and/or best practice in terms of sanitizing html that is returned from an api call in a vuejs app.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it myself, but vue-sanitize looks like it might be nice for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sanitize

Comment: I had some time and wrote up a longer explanation here, https://www.raymondcamden.com/2019/11/26/sanitizing-html-in-vuejs.